# How to create a Project in Bitbucket Cloud using Rest API?

Tags: bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I'm referring [this Bitbucket API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/teams/%7Busername%7D/projects/) for creating a new project within a team. But getting 404 error:

```
There is no API hosted at this URL.\n\nFor information about our API's, please refer to the documentation at: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/
```

.

I've tried different options in place of {teams-in-space} in https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/{teams-in-space}/projects/

Tried with team name, team uuid and username (account name) but got the same error.

Is anyone successful in creating project in Bitbucket Cloud using REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the trailing / in the URL  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/{teams-in-space}/projects/
It works fine now after adding the trailing /